# Azure-aks: programatically watch AKS creation status using Java

Tags: java, azure-aks, java-threads, azure-sdk-for-java

I am writing test cases for an IaaC project. The use case is like the following:

```
Given I do not have a AKS cluster
And I call an api to create a cluster
Then I have a cluster up and running
```

In the above scenario for 3rd step, I would like to implement two things, which are as follows:

1. First wait for the AKS resource to be created and
2. Once the resource is created, wait for the its provisioning state to be success

I searched the Azure documentation to see if there are any out of the box Watchers that azure provides as a part of it's azure-sdk-for-java. But did not find any. Could somebody share your knowledge or experience is solving such a problem statement?